# How to do lazy loading when using ViewPager2?

Tags: androidx, android-viewpager2

I'm changing my code to androidX, I used to store fragments in viewpager and each fragment contains several lists, now I have problems about lazy loading when using viewpager2, is there some sample code from google?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
abstract class LazyFragment : Fragment() {

    private var isInitData : Boolean = false            // flag bit to determine whether the data is initialized
    private var isVisibleToUser : Boolean = false       // flags to determine whether fragments are visible
    private var isPrepareView : Boolean = false         // flag bit to determine that view has been loaded to avoid null pointer operations

    override fun onViewCreated(@NonNull view: View, @Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        isPrepareView = true // At this point the view has been loaded and set to true
    }


    override fun onHiddenChanged(hidden: Boolean) {
        super.onHiddenChanged(hidden)
        if (!hidden) {
            lazyInitData()
        }
    }


    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        isVisibleToUser = true
        lazyInitData() // Load lazily
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        isVisibleToUser = false
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        lazyInitData() // Load lazily
    }

    //


    /**
     * Lazy Loading Method
     */
    private fun lazyInitData(){
        if(setFragmentTarget()){
            if(!isInitData && isVisibleToUser && isPrepareView) {
                loadData()
            }
        }else {
            if(!isInitData && isVisibleToUser && isPrepareView) {
                loadData()
            }else if (!isInitData && parentFragment ==null && isPrepareView ){
                loadData()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun loadData() {
        initData(); // Load data
        isInitData = true; // Has the data flag been loaded and reassigned to true
    }


    /**
     * Method of loading data, implemented by subclasses
     */
    abstract fun initData()

    /**
     * Setting Fragment target, implemented by subclasses
     */
    abstract fun setFragmentTarget(): Boolean
```

What you need to do is this

(For each of the fragments you use in ViewPager2, make the fragment extend LazyFragment):

1. override onCreateView() to inflate the layout
2. override  setFragmentTarget () where it returns true or false based on whether or not you want that fragment to be loaded immediately or lazily
3. override initData() and put your logic into it